# I fugured en français?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

**Salut à tous**

*Je me demandais s'il y avait des équivalents pour les expressions: «I figured», «I figured it out» en français?*

Comment: Do you have a specific context/example in mind?

Comment: Ça se trouve facilement dans [un dictionnaire.](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/figure)

Comment: If you're going to ask a translation/dictionary question, please give examples of your own tries or somewhere you checked but weren't satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait dire:

> J'ai compris.
>
> Eurêka.
>
> J'ai pigé (familiar, spoken only).
>
> J'ai trouvé.